# What Are Some Decent ISPs That Host Subversion

Tags: svn

I want a recommendation on an ISP which has Subversion installed so I can get a repository started.  So far I found out discount.asp doesn't have that on their servers and will not support it.  So I'm looking for a recommendation

Comment: Do you really mean an ISP (Internet service provider) who provides you with a connection to the Internet, or do you mean a hosting provider?

Comment: [Q&A is hard, let's go shopping!](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/23/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)

Answer (score 8):

What's your price range?
Do you want a straght SVN provider or do you want to host a website too?

For Straight SVN Hosting Check out

http://cvsdude.com/

http://www.assembla.com/

Only Hosting provider I can think of with SVN support (outside of a VPS provider) would be

http://www.dreamhost.com

Comment: I'm just going to throw out the fact that I just moved domain and hosting from GoDaddy to Dreamhost just because of the things they offer, including SVN repositories. The transition was painless.

Answer (score 4):

I'd like to second [www.dreamhost.com](http://www.dreamhost.com) as a superb solution / value for money.
I've been with them for about 2 years, there are limits on size/bandwidth, but they're so ridiculously high you can basically consider it unlimited for any reasonable project.

I've never had a server issue or any downtime (although I have heard others have). They seem open and trustworthy.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't used them yet, but after reading about their offering, I am seriously considering using http://projectlocker.com/ for my next subversion based project. The have fairly cheap pricing (free up to $30 a month), and they recently got a plug from [Scott Mitchell](http://scottonwriting.net/sowblog/posts/13849.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Are these sites trustworthy enough? After all they have **your** intellectual property on file. You don't want them to use it themselves or give it to your competitors.

Comment: You do want to do some basic background on the company.  However, these business stake their reputations and their employees' livelihoods on protecting customer data.  If you're not working with financial data or government secrets, it's impractical for someone to try to use your IP to their advantage.  Someone would have to learn your code, then research your competitors, then devise a plan to maximize profit.  Criminals are usually opportunists; that's too much work.  It's most important to be concerned that hosting companies have a plan to protect you from the proverbial data center fire.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend http://beanstalkapp.com/

Answer (score 1):

There are some restrictions on the free accounts (namely 200MB) but we've recently set up an account with [Assembla](http://www.assembla.com) for a small project. It provides SVN (optionally externally hosted), Trac, a wiki, and several other built-in tools, similar to SourceForge. Your project does not need to be open source.

Answer (score 1):

I have been using [wush.net](http://wush.net) for about 9 months and am pretty stoked.  Especially considering the fact that you get integrated Trac when you upgrade to pro (which kinda pays for itself if you have a few repo's because you get discounts on the additional).

Answer (score 0):

[csoft.net](http://csoft.net) is pretty good.  They've been around for a long time, they're cheap, good, open source friendly, very geek friendly, and accounts come with SVN (and with the more expensive plans, a ton of other features).  Also, ever tried to deal with frontline tech support at a big host (like, ick, 1&1) where you had a sneaking suspicion you were actually dealing with a very poorly programmed Eliza bot rather than a human?  Yeah, well, csoft isn't like that.  :-)

If you're looking for something a little more user friendly, you might check out [Unfuddle](http://unfuddle.com/).  I haven't used them personally but they get a lot of good press here on SO, and they've got a nice feature set.

Answer (score 0):

I use http://devguard.com/ .  Very cheap, but also very reliable.  Integrated Trac, SSL, web-based ACL and user management.  SVN scripts, eg. commit hooks. I tried CVSDude before and that didn't work out.

Answer (score 0):

I have an account with www.codespaces.com They have svn hosting, wiki, forum, project management, issue tracking and admin all built in. I have been using the service for 6 months and I am happy with the level of service they off.

Answer (score 0):

I've used csoft.net for 6 years.  They've been reliable, and inexpensive. Their documentation is good.

Answer (score 0):

**[Site5](http://site5.com)** offers ssh access, which means you can use svn+ssh for very cheap repositories with practically unlimited size/bandwidth.

Answer (score 0):

I will vote for [Assembla](http://www.assembla.com/features), its big feature set can not be compared with unfuddle, beanstalkapp or any other svn only hosting provider.

Answer (score 0):

I've used [unfuddle](http://unfuddle.com/) for several projects, and I'm really happy with them. Their admin UI is great and they also have some project management tools that are fairly useful.

They have a free version that's decent if you don't need much.

Answer (score 0):

I've used SVN through Dreamhost for quite some time and I've found them to be really good. A bit slow for me as I'm based in Australia but otherwise excellent